# how to create a jmagick application

Tags: java, windows, installation, imagemagick, jmagick

I'm very new to jmagick. Can anyone help me out how to start a jmagick simple application ?

Comment: This is very vague. What are you trying to achieve? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @armandino thanks for ur reply i need to resize image through imagick magick i have written code and installed jmagick but im getting this error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class magick.ImageInfo please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate(?) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150503/image-magick-java

Comment: @armandino i need to use imagemagick....please help me out dat is using j2se where should i keep jmagick.dll file??? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class magick.ImageInfo`

means that jmagick.jar is not on your `CLASSPATH`. You need to add it to the `CLASSPATH`.

In addition, you also need to install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). It's the native library that does all the work. After installation you will need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable that points to the location where ImageMagick was installed. The setup depends on what OS you're using. There are detailed [instructions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jmagick/index.php?title=Installing_JMagick) on the wiki. For a code example, see the link provided by Andrew. This should get you started.

**Edit:** [How to install JMagick on Windows](http://boristechnicalnotes.blogspot.com/2008/10/installing-jmagick-639-on-windows-xp.html).

Comment: yaa i have installed imagemagick and i have set my class path im working on windows xp sp3 ..what more should i do

Comment: You need to provide more details. If you're still getting `NoClassDefFoundError` that means you haven't set your `CLASSPATH` properly.

Comment: thanks very much i have copied dll file in the folder where c://programfiles/imagemagick/ and i have set my classpath correctly im working on netbeans...but im still getting that error ..pls help me thanks in advance