# How to convert images in apple’s new HEIC format to jpg in java?

Tags: java, ios, jpeg, heic

I have few thousand images in HEIC format that need to be converted to jpg/png. Conversion needs to happen in a backend process preferably java.

What is the best way available to do this in java? If not, can anyone point me to a tutorial that explains how jpg can be obtained from HEIC format?

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/) is great for converting images from the command line. There are two different Java interfaces, [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org) and [im4java](https://im4java.sourceforge.net).

See the [Image magick java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150503/image-magick-java) question for tips how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use im4java and ImageMagick to convert heic to jpeg. The following code may help you.

```
public static byte[] convertHEICtoJPEG(byte[] heicBytes) throws IOException, InterruptedException, IM4JavaException {
    IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
    op.addImage("-");
    op.addImage("jpeg:-");
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".heic");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        fos.write(heicBytes);
    }
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
    Pipe pipeIn  = new Pipe(fis,null);
    ConvertCmd convert = new ConvertCmd();
    convert.setSearchPath(IMAGE_MAGICK_PATH);
    convert.setInputProvider(pipeIn); 
    Stream2BufferedImage s2b = new Stream2BufferedImage();
    convert.setOutputConsumer(s2b);
    convert.run(op);
    BufferedImage image = s2b.getImage();
    byte[] imageBytes = imageToBytes(image);
    fis.close();
    return imageBytes;

}


private static byte[] imageToBytes(BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", baos);
    baos.flush();
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    return imageBytes;
}
```

Comment: private static final String IMAGE_MAGICK_PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI";

Comment: You are aware that you can [edit] your answer? ;)

Answer (score -2):

I've bumped into libheif library recently that is designed to fulfill your task - https://github.com/strukturag/libheif

There is also blog post that explains how to create wrapper bash script and use it to perform conversion using command line : https://stuffjasondoes.com/2019/07/10/batch-convert-heic-to-jpg-in-linux/

I presume you can call above script with ZT Process Executor ( https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) or just use old plain Runtime.exec().

Or even get fancier and use JNI to compile with above library for better performance.

Comment: running CLI scripts programmatically is super hacky and should be the absolute last resort